# applicationContextProvider is not being called

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 3.0.3.

I would like to use the applicationContextProvider so I declared:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.mycompany.util.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

and my ApplicationContextProvider:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext _applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = _applicationContext;

    }

}
```

But the set is never being called!

and whenever I am using `ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()` returns null.

why is it?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `getApplicationContext()` *after* the context has finished initializing?

Comment: How would I know if it's before or after? I am calling it from a another bean inside spring

Comment: If your bean is instantiated during the start-up, it could get instantiated before the ApplicationContext is injected into your ApplicationContextProvider, and call getApplicationContext "too soon". What do you need the provider for, can't you just inject the dependencies directly into the bean that uses the context?

Comment: Why are you using a static `ApplicationContext` field at all? If you have code that uses the context, why not inject it directly into that?

Comment: even after the server is up it's still null! I need it for web service that is using spring bean

Comment: You can just @Autowire it into the web service.  See example but principle is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem may be that your getter is static.  So its possible for you to call it before Spring has created an instance of ApplicationContextProvider.

You need to refer to the bean 'applicationContextProvider' that Spring has created for you when Spring is "ready" for you to use it.  See [Bean lifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle)

E.g. via a Junit test with your bean in 'app-context.xml' in src/test/resources

```
package com.mycompany.util;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:app-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApplicationContextProviderTest {

    @Autowired // Injected by Spring when bean is "ready"
    ApplicationContextProvider contextProvider;


    @Test
    public void testContext() {
        assertNotNull(contextProvider);
        ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
        assertNotNull(context);

        System.out.println("My context has " + context.getBeanDefinitionCount() + " beans");
    }
}
```

Then this gets a green bar for applicationContext being set.

Example output (don't leave System.out in the test btw).

```
INFO : org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class com.mycompany.util.ApplicationContextProviderTest]: using defaults.
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4c331059: startup date [Sun Feb 27 13:38:13 GMT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4b1c2b67: defining beans [applicationContextProvider,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
My context has 5 beans
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4c331059: startup date [Sun Feb 27 13:38:13 GMT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4b1c2b67: defining beans [applicationContextProvider,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

app-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.mycompany.util.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: It's a good answer, however the link for `Bean Lifecycle` is dead now.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question with already accepted answer, but for me it wasn't really clear why the `setApplicationContext()` method wasn't being called on the `applicationContextProvider`. The answer provided **how** but really not the **why**.

Spring creates beans using lazy strategy: a bean will only be created the first time it is needed. That is why example in the accepted answer works: the bean is needed by `ApplicationContextProviderTest` and so it is created at that point, and not before, and `setApplicationContext()` method is being called at that point in time and everything works as intended.

However, if your bean is not auto-wired anywhere none of this will happen. In this case the solution is to tell Spring to not use lazy instantiation, i.e.:

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvider" lazy-init="false" class="com.mycompany.util.ApplicationContextProvider" />
```

This way, the bean will be created on application startup and method `setApplicationContext()` will be called at that time. You can then use the bean afterwords, provided that the *usage* happens after application startup is done.

Of course, much better way is to auto-wire the bean wherever you need it, but sometime it is not possible (read: legacy apps).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are doing something the wrong way here... Do you want to get access to Spring beans from object not managed by Spring? How about [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getRequiredWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29):

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

But `WebApplicationContextUtils` should always be treated as a last resort because this is not a *Spring way*. Are you sure you cannot integrate web services with Spring somehow? For instance with Apache CXF one can simply implement WS endpoint as a Spring bean or inject client proxy to other beans...

Using static fields is always asking yourself for trouble. I am sure you can achieve your goals in a more elegant fashion.

Comment: The static field is not the problem.  It is calling the accessor method too early in the bean life cycle.